# Thread en c++ error compilacion

Tags: c++

Estoy empezando con threads y he estado siguien varios tutos y creo que esta todo bien, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da [error](http://pastebin.com/erqvxkWy).
El codigo:

```
    int main() {
    int num_it, num_threads,energy=50000;
    string sequence;
    cout << "Enter number of iterations: ";
    cin >> num_it;
    cout << endl << "Enter number of threads: ";
    cin >> num_threads;

    //thread* t = new thread[num_threads]; ---> Intento con array
    vector<thread> t; // Con vectores
    string* seq = new string[num_threads];
    for (int j = 0;j < num_it;j++) {
        for (int i = 0;i <= num_threads;i++) {
            seq[i] = gen_seq();
            t.push_back(thread(function_E, seq[i], sequence, energy));
        }
        int i = 5;

        for (auto &tt : t) { tt.join(); }
        for (int i = 0;i <= num_threads;i++) {
            seq[i].clear();
        //  t[i].join();
        }
    }
    cout << energy << endl << sequence << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

y la funcion que llamo en los threads:

```
    void function_E(string temp_seq,string &good_seq,int &energy) {
    int i = 1;
    int e = 0;

    //string seq = gen_seq();
    static mutex m;

    for (i = 1;i <= L - 1;i++) {

        e = e + (function_c(i, temp_seq)*function_c(i, temp_seq));
    }

    if (e < energy) {
        m.lock();
        energy = e;
        good_seq = temp_seq;
        m.unlock();

        }

}
```

La verdad es que no se a que se debe el error, he probado todo... Esto esta hecho con VS2015, por si sirve de algo. Gracias de antezarpa por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es que los `std::thread` no admiten el paso por referencia, aunque la puedes simular:

```
t.push_back(std::thread(function_E, seq[i], std::ref(sequence), std::ref(energy)));
```

`std::ref` devuelve un objeto de tipo `std::reference_wrapper<T>` que es un objeto copiable y asignable, convertible a `T&`, de ahí que no necesites cambiar los parámetros de la función.

Es una manera no invasiba de pasar referencias a través de objetos copiables.

Comment: La marco como respuesta, es la que me ha servido. Si bien la anterior es buena y muy didactica, esta es mas sencilla. Gracias ;)

Answer (score 3):

Antes de responderte, un par de sugerencias:

Esto:

```
string* seq = new string[num_threads];
```

Quedaría mucho mejor así:

```
std::vector<std::string> seq;
seq.reserve(num_threads);
```

Entre otras cosas, se te ha olvidado poner el correspondiente `delete[]`, lo que implica fugas de memoria y con este diseño te lo puedes ahorrar.

Con el tema de la vida de las variables, lo suyo es minimizar la misma al mínimo imprescindible. Esto:

```
int i = 1;
// ...

for (i = 1;i <= L - 1;i++) {
  e = e + i;
}
```

Debería quedar tal que:

```
for(int i=1; i<L; i++){
  e += i;
}
```

Y bueno, comentarte respecto a tu error que los hilos no admiten funciones con referencias. El constructor de `std::thread` crea una copia de los parámetros y llama con ellos a la función que le indiques, por lo que usar referencias no te va a permitir actualizar dichos valores.

Para devolver valores hay varias opciones. Mi preferida son los futures. `std::future` es un mecanismo que permite crear llamadas asíncronas. Con `std::future` podemos atender otras tareas hasta que nuestra ejecución asíncrona nos devuelve un resultado, momento en el que podremos recuperarlo y continuar con nuestros menesteres.

Una de las formas más limpias que he encontrado de hacer esto es la que comento a continuación.

Primero creamos una estructura que encapsule la tarea a ejecutar de forma asíncrona (para ello podemos utilizar el operador función). Además de esto la clase debe almacenar un miembro de tipo `std::promise`. Esta clase es la que se va a conectar con `std::future` para indicar que ya hay un resultado disponible:

```
struct CodigoPesado
{
  std::promise<int> promise;

  void operator()()
  {
    // Código pesado

    // Devolvemos el resultado de nuestra función
    promise.set_value(2);
  }
};
```

Ahora creamos una instancia de esta clase y le pedimos un `std::future`:

```
CodigoPesado codigoPesado;
std::future<int> future = codigoPesado.promise.get_future();
```

Ya podemos ejecutar nuestra tarea de forma asíncrona:

```
std::thread hilo(std::ref(codigoPesado));
```

La espera la podemos realizar de dos formas: activa o pasiva.

Espera activa:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds espera(100);
while( future.wait_for(espera) == std::future_status::timeout )
  std::cout << '.' << std::flush;
```

Espera pasiva:

```
// La ejecución se quedará esperando en esta llamada hasta que el resultado
// esté listo
future.wait();
```

Y finalmente recuperamos el valor:

```
int valor = future.get();
std::cout << valor << '\n';
```

Para incorporar esto a tu código puedes crear una estructura, te valdría con que `std::future` devolviese un `std::tuple` o un `std::pair`.

```
std::future<std::tuple<std::string,int>> future;

// Sobreescribimos los valores de sequence y energy
std::tie(sequence,energy) = future.get();
```

**NOTA:** `std::future` no permite llamadas al constructor copia (salvo para sintaxis *move*) ni múltiples llamadas a `get()`. Para hacer uso de esta funcionalidad es necesario recurrir a `std::shared_future`.

Por supuesto también puedes optar por ahorrarte la gestión de `std::thread` y utilizar `std::async`. Es más limpio y te devuelve un future automáticamente:

```
std::tuple<std::string,int> function_e(...);

std::future<std::tuple<std::string,int>> future
  = std::async(std::launch::async,function_E,...);
std::tie(sequence,energy) = future.get();
```

La pega de `std::async`, es que su uso por defecto no es asíncrono sino síncrono (ignoro los motivos), por lo que si no pones `std::launch_async` la ejecución será totalmente síncrona.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido de ayuda :) Respecto a lo del principio que pones sobre minimizar las variables, ya lo hago(si miras el main, lo hago asi) solo que ahi se me ha debido pasar. Gracias de nuevo.